# Changing File Permissions using SSH and CHMOD to allow file uploads

Tags: php, mysql, ssh, chmod

```
    Warning: move_uploaded_file(activities.png): 
failed to open stream:
 Permission denied in /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/backoffice/db/changelogo.php on line 17
Warning: move_uploaded_file():
 Unable to move '/tmp/phpTNQXEi' to 'activities.png' in /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/backoffice/db/changelogo.php on line 17
```

So I get a permission denied due to incorrect file permissions for this .php script.

How would allow file uploads and not get permission denied using SSH (or SFTP) to get this to allow image uploads.

here is the php script for reference purposes:

```
    <?php
include 'realtydevkit.php';
session_start();

umask(0077);

$name = $_FILES['yourlogo']['name'];
$tmpname = $_FILES['yourlogo']['tmp_name'];
$error = $_FILES['yourlogo']['error'];

ini_set("display_errors", 1);

echo $error;

if ($name) {
    $directory = $name;
    $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $type = "logo";

    $file = move_uploaded_file($tmpname, $directory);

    if ($file) {    
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO usercontent
    (`userid`, `type`, `url`) VALUES
    ('$userid', '$type', '$directory')");
    echo 'Uploaded';
    echo "<img src='".$directory."'/>";
    } else {
    echo 'There was an error moving the file.';
    }

    chmod($directory, 0644);
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real issue here is that the file is not being written with proper permissions in the first place. I suspect you aren't setting your `umask` in the application ahead of time:

I would be careful with this setting as it is easy to create security issues for yourself by setting global read/write on any given uploaded file. Take the usual security precautions and perhaps set read/write to only the web user and not in a public directory.  Perhaps even set up a job that runs on-demand or on the minute that will move these for you to decrease your security threat.

From a comment in the docs, a quick how-to with this:

```
<?php
// files will create as -rw-------
umask(0077);

// create a file, eg fopen()

// give access: -rw-r--r--
chmod('/path/to/file', 0644);
?>
```

More information in the docs:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php

Comment: Thanks a lot! But, this is for an existing file, I changed the permissions for it via SSH, but, it doesn't affect the permission denied. This is going to be very useful to affect rw priveliges though. I'm going to try putting umask and CHMOD in my existing php script to see if it will allow a file upload (an image perse)

Comment: Check my original post to see what I did wrong. I still get a permission denied error.

Answer (score -1):

You could possibly use PHP's [built in](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) `chmod()` function.

This will allow you to change the permissions of the folder you want to transfer the file to.  You could always chmod it back once the file has been moved.

Alternatively, you can simply chmod the folder manually before anyone reaches your site.

Please be careful when dealing with permissions on files and folders that reside within your server.  These files could possibly be accessed from the outside world and setting very open permissions (0777 for example)  would allow any script or anyone to create,delete and alter files within that folder.

Comment: Thank you, check PhilWinkle's post and my original for reference purposes.